# Troubleshooting rvest

Tags: r, xml, rvest

I have the following html string:

```
html <- '<head>
    <dd>
        "Line 1 : abc
        Line 2 : def
        Line 3 : ghi
        Line 4 : jkl
        Line 5 : mno"
    </dd>
</head>'
```

If I want to extract everything between the < dd > tags, then I can use the XML or rvest packages with no problems:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(XML)

xpath <- '//dd'

html %>% 
    XML::htmlParse(., asText=TRUE) %>% 
    XML::xpathSApply(., path = xpath, xmlValue)


html %>% 
    xml2::read_html() %>%
    rvest::html_nodes(xpath=xpath) %>%
    rvest::html_text()
```

This produces:

```
'\n        "Line 1 : abc\n        Line 2 : def\n        Line 3 : ghi\n        Line 4 : jkl\n        Line 5 : mno"\n    '
'\n        "Line 1 : abc\n        Line 2 : def\n        Line 3 : ghi\n        Line 4 : jkl\n        Line 5 : mno"\n    '
```

But I only want to extract the text from Line 4. So I update my Xpath and keep the remainder of the code the same:

```
xpath <- 'substring-after(substring-after(substring-before(//dd, "Line 5"), "Line 3"), "\n")'

html %>% 
    XML::htmlParse(., asText=TRUE) %>% 
    XML::xpathSApply(., path = xpath, xmlValue)


html %>% 
    xml2::read_html() %>%
    rvest::html_nodes(xpath=xpath) %>%
    rvest::html_text()
```

This time XML works but rvest does not work:

```
'        Line 4 : jkl\n        '
Error in nodes_duplicated(nodes): Expecting an external pointer: [type=character].
```

How can I obtain the desired result of "Line 4 : jkl\n" using rvest?

Comment: I suggest you bring the whole text / corpus in. Turn the HTML table into a tibble.  And only then worry about pulling out line 4.